# Result from query with join loses order when converted to POJO list

Tags: java, oracle, sql-order-by, jooq

I'm using JOOQ to create a native query to an Oracle 12 database.
When I convert the result to my POJO the order from the order by clause is lost.

Basically I'm joining two tables, Tasks and Variables. A Task can have many Variables.

I'm converting the results to my POJO this way:

```
select.fetchGroups(Task.class, Variable.class);

public class Task{

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String formKey;

        private List<Variable> variables = new ArrayList<Variable>();


getters()/setters()

...

hashCode()

...

equals()

}

public class Variable{

    private String vId;
    private String vName;
    private String vValue;
    private String vType;

getters()/setters()

...

hashCode()

...

equals()


}
```

I'm trying to "plug" my order clause at the end of the select manually (as didn't find a way to build it up with the jooq sintax, some insights on that will be appreciated):

The jooq dslcontext

```
@Autowired
private DSLContext dsl;
```

The list that is populated

```
Map<Task, List<Variable>> response;
```

The plain order by sentence.

```
String orderClause = " case when V.NAME_ = '"+sortColumn+"' then V.TEXT_ end "+sortDirection;
```

(If I log the plain SQL of this, the result is correctly ordered)

```
SelectSeekStep1<Record, Object> selectOrdered = select.orderBy(DSL.field(orderClause));

response = selectOrdered.fetchGroups(Task.class, Variable.class);
```

At this point my response variable is already a map, but the order is lost.

There's no error messages or exceptions, the Map is returned as expected, but the order is lost.

Please tell me if I'm missing some critical detail, and I'll add it.

Comment: if you want preserver insertion order in Map then go for LinkedHashMap it will solve your issue.

Comment: 1) *"as didn't find a way to build it up with the jooq sintax, some insights on that will be appreciated"* Can you show your commplete jOOQ code and why you couldn't achieve what you wanted with jOOQ? 2), why do you distinguish between `Task` and `TaskQuery`? How are they different? 3) what does the complete query look like?

Comment: @LukasEder sorry, those TaskQuery were a typo, I changed them to just "Task". About the complete jooq, it's a long query but the sql output is the expected, so I thing that is working just right.

Comment: It's really difficult to help you without understanding what *exactly* you're trying to achieve with that `ORDER BY` clause. To me, it doesn't look like it's doing what you *think* it's doing, even in SQL. Or, what you posted is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various `fetchGroups()` methods use a `LinkedHashMap` behind the scenes, which they return to you, and they iterate the records in fetch order, so any order you provide the jOOQ query with is stable with respect to these methods.

From what you've shown, you're ordering by some `V` columns, which probably stands for `Variable`. You cannot possibly expect that order to be retained when grouping by `Task` in the client, although the ordering is stable *per* `Task`. I'll illustrate. If this is what you're getting from the database (because you order by variable):

```
TASK    VARIABLE
1       A
2       B
3       C
1       D
2       E
```

Then, these `fetchGroups()` methods will produce the following client side grouping:

```
TASK = 1
  VARIABLE = [A, D]
TASK = 2
  VARIABLE = [B, E]
TASK = 3
  VARIABLE = [C]
```

Comment: So I guess will have to order the resulting map with some Comparator implementation then. There's no other way to get around this with jooq right?

Comment: @Migerusantte: I think we have a classic case of the [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/) here. You're asking about Y (some projected jOOQ problem), but I think your real problem is X (wrong SQL, or wrong jOOQ API usage). I'm not sure how to help you until you've explained what you *really* try to achieve (ideally with some sample data) and, maybe, what your current query is.

Comment: Well, to be honest the explanation that you gave on this response is exactly the case of what its happenning, however I cannot post complete code here cause it will be way too long and we'll get to the same point. I think I understood the problem, and will sort the resulting map entries into a ordered list. Thanks.